# En el nuevo menú desplegable, el nombre del sitio se expande en 2 líneas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, barra-superior

El nombre del sitio se expande en otra línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambiamos el texto `cerrar sesión` por `salir` el problema se corrige sin tocar estilos (al menos en Chrome).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás también habría que aumentar el ancho.

Comment: Yo no veo lo mismo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZSpr.png creo que depende de la resolución... aunque prefiero la opción _"salir"_.

Comment: Tambien en firefox el cambio a **salir** ayuda. Resolución 1600 x 900

Answer (score 5):

Se ha cambiado a "Salir"

Esperen unas 2 horas para que el cambio se active.